# android.preview is not available

Tags: android, notifications, wear-os

Using SDK Manager, I downloaded all the modules in AndroidL.

In Android wear, to show a notification I need to import a package import `android.preview.support.wearable.notifications.WearableNotifications` which says cannot resolve symbol 'preview'.

I then cross verified my downloads in SDK manager. It show I have downloaded all in AndroidL(API 20, L priview). I do I get this preview package to show notification ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as `WearableNotifications` now. You are trying to use old code from **Android Wear SDK preview** - that was posted before **final Android Wear SDK** release. Since Google I/O 2014 the wearable classes are part of standard support v4 lib. So please just use `NotificationCompat` instead.﻿

You can see more details about migrating from the `preview` to final SDK release in this post on **Android Developers Blog**:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/07/porting-your-wear-developer-preview.html